# Is the lifetime of a reference extended?

Tags: c++, reference, lifetime

I'd like to pass a reference into a function. This code does not work, as I'd expect:

```
struct A {
};

void foo(A& a) {
    // do something with a
}

int main(int, char**) {
    foo(A());
}
```

I get the compile error

> invalid initialization of non-const reference of type `A&` from an rvalue of type `A`

But when I just add the method `A& ref()` to `A` like below and call it before passing it along, it seems I can use `a`. When debugging, the `A` object is destroyed after `foo()` is called:

```
struct A {
    A& ref() {
        return *this;
    }
};

void foo(A& a) {
    // do something with a
}

int main(int, char**) {
    foo(A().ref());
}
```

Is this valid code according to the standard? Does calling `ref()` magically extend the lifetime of the object until `foo()` returns?

Comment: Although this is technically, it's much simpler to simply change the function parameter to either a `const A &`, or `A &&`.

Comment: Your first snippet doesn't work because you are trying to pass an rvalue reference to a function taking a non const lvalue reference, which makes no sense. This is not allowed to prevent you from doing something wrong with A in f(), because changing A in f() would have no effect.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik in the code where I actually use this I'd like to modify a before assigning it to another object.

Comment: Out of curiosity, which compiler are you using? Clang?

Comment: @FabioTurati I've tried g++, Visual Studio 2015, IBM's xlc++, and now clang as well.

Comment: @martinus how about assign first, then modify the copy?

Comment: So? Nothing that I wrote prohibits "modifying before assigning to another object".

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I can't use const&, and I can't use && because unfortunately no c++11 allowed in my project.

Comment: I see no reason that would prohibit the use of `const &`.

Comment: Is there a reason `A` has to be constructed outside `foo`? It seems odd to use a ctor with no arguments to create a temp and then just immediately pass that temp to a function without changing its state at all. From what I can tell there is no reason why the construction of `A` can't be done inside `foo`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your code is perfectly valid.

In this line

```
foo(A().ref());
```

The instance of a temporary `A` lives until the end of the statement (`;`).

That's why it's safe to pass `A&` returned from `ref()` to `foo` (as long as `foo` doesn't store it).

`ref()` by itself does not extend any lifetime, but it helps by returning an lvalue reference.

What happens in the case of `foo(A());` ? Here the temporary is passed as an rvalue. And in C++ an rvalue does not bind to non-const lvalue references (even in C++11, an rvalue *reference* does not bind to non-const lvalue references).

From this [Visual C++ blog article about rvalue references](http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2009/02/03/rvalue-references-c-0x-features-in-vc10-part-2.aspx):

> ... C++ doesn't want you to accidentally modify temporaries, but directly
>   calling a non-const member function on a modifiable rvalue is explicit, so
>   it's allowed ...

Comment: but if this is allowed and valid, why is `foo(A());` not allowed?

Comment: That's because an rvalue cannot be bound to a non-const reference.

Comment: You should mention explicity that if `foo(A())` worked, it would have `A()` last to the end of the statement; lifetime isn't an issue here.

Comment: @martinus: You can't bind a non-`const` directly, but if you can get around that _type_ limitation, the reference-extending rules actually still apply. They're defined in broader terms.

Answer (score 7):

`A()` creates a temporary object of type `A`. The object exists until the end of the full expression in which it is created. The problem in your original code is **not** the lifetime of this temporary; it's that the function takes its argument as a non-const reference, and you're not allowed to pass a temporary object as a non-const reference. The simplest change is for `foo` to take it's argument by const reference, if that's appropriate to what the function does:

```
void foo(const A&);
int main() {
    foo(A());
}
```

Comment: I can't pass a const reference, in the code where I use it I have to modify a before assigning it to another object.

Comment: You're not allowed to pass a temporary object as a non-const **lvalue** reference, as a non const rvalue reference it is allowed (implicitly creating a temporary variable).

Answer (score 5):

There are several questions in this question. I'll attempt to address all of them:

---

First, you cannot pass a temporary (prvalue) of type `A` to a function taking `A&` because non-const lvalue references cannot bind to rvalues. That's a language restriction. If you want to be able to pass a temporary, you either need to take a parameter of type `A&&` or of type `A const&` - the latter since temporaries *can* bind to const lvalue references.

---

> Is this valid code according to the standard? Does calling `ref()` magically extend the lifetime of the object until `foo()` returns?

There is no lifetime extension going on in your program at all. From [class.temp]:

> There are three contexts in which temporaries are destroyed at a different point than the end of the full-expression. The first context is when a default constructor is called to initialize an element of an array with
>   no corresponding initializer (8.6). The second context is when a copy constructor is called to copy an element
>   of an array while the entire array is copied (5.1.5, 12.8). [...] The third context is when a reference is bound to a temporary.

None of those contexts apply. We are never binding a reference to a temporary in this code. `ref()` binds `*this` to an `A&`, but `*this` is not a temporary, and then that resulting reference is simply passed into `foo()`.

Consider this variant of your program:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    A& ref() { return *this; }
    ~A() { std::cout << "~A()\n"; }
};

int main() {
    auto& foo = A().ref();
    std::cout << "----\n";
}
```

which prints

```
~A()
----
```

illustrating that there is no lifetime extension.

---

If instead of binding the result of `ref()` to a reference we instead bound a member:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    A& ref() { return *this; }
    int x;

    ~A() { std::cout << "~A()\n"; }
};

int main() {
    auto&& foo = A().x;
    std::cout << "----\n";
}
```

then we actually are binding a temporary to a reference and that third context applies - the lifetime of the complete object of the subobject to which the reference is bound is persisted for the lifetime of the reference. So this code prints:

```
----
~A()
```

Comment: _"`*this` is not a temporary"_ It certainly is. But you're right that its lifetime doesn't require extending.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit `*this` is always an lvalue though.